# Fundamental Theorem of Calculus on line integrals

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I've been shown by my lecturer how to find a function $f$ given $\nabla f$ using the FTC for line integrals. You use $$\int_C {\nabla f}\cdot d\textbf{r}=f(\textbf{x})-f(\textbf{x}_0) $$ And consider the parametrization from $\textbf{x}_0$ to $\textbf{x}$ by the line $$\textbf{r}(t)=\textbf{x}_0+t(\textbf{x}-\textbf{x}_0), \;\;\; t\in[0,1)$$ Now for simplicity take $\textbf{x}_0=\textbf{0}$. Rearrange the first equation to get $$f(\textbf{x})=\int_C {\nabla f}\cdot d\textbf{r} +f(\textbf{0})$$ Now you can calculate the integral. However I can't seem to get it to work for this example: $$f(x,y,z)=x^2z+e^y+xy,\;\;\;\; \nabla f=(2xz+y,e^y+x,x^2)$$
I know $\textbf{r}(t)=t\textbf{x}$ and therefore $\textbf{r}'(t)=\textbf{x}$
$$\nabla f(\textbf{r}(t))=(2t^2xz+ty,e^{ty}+tx,t^2x^2)$$ Using dot product I get the integral as $$\int_0^1 3t^2x^2z+2txy+ye^{ty}dt$$ Which gives the answer $$f(\textbf{x})=x^2z+xy+y(e^y-1)+f(\textbf{0})$$ Which is not the right answer from above. Can anyone see where I've gone wrong?

Comment: $\int y e^{ty} dt = e^{ty}$, not $ye^{ty}$. If you fix that, everything works.

Comment: Of course, thanks very much :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to build an parametric equation of $y$ and $z$ as functions of $t$ or constant values. You aren't able to integrate $y$ and $z$ that easy because they are functions of $t$.

Comment: He has a line from the origin to a fixed point $(x,y,z)$. $x$, $y$ and $z$ are constants.

Comment: But I'm integrating w.r.t $t$. Therefore $x,y,z$ act as constants.

Comment: I think that $r(t)$ defines a line segment, and that x,y and z aren't constants on this line segment... Your x,y and z change over this line segment! Therefor you cannot disregard them in the integral... r(t) defines a parametrization of a curve!

Comment: @MarkisaB You are confusing the coordinates of $r(t)$ with the variables George1811 chose to name the fixed point. $r(t) =  \langle tx, ty, tz \rangle$. If the usage of $x,y,z$ in this way bothers you, you can rewrite the whole thing with $(a,b,c)$ as the fixed point, so $r(t) =  \langle ta, tb, tc \rangle$.